# SSIS Data Type Conversion

Tags: ssis

I am having an excel file with huge records. I want to import it into OLEDB destination in SSIS. While using **Data Type Conversion** to change the data type, One of the column "Date" is showing as "Unicode string [DT_WSTR]". How to change it to datetime?

Can some one please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

> DT_DBTIMESTAMP

if you have datetime into your DB.

For your string format:

> yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

If you can get your string dates into that format, you're guaranteed to get a correct conversion.

Comment: In excel file whether I need to change the format for "date" column?

Comment: If you can or stored your date string into a variable and you can use functions to change it if you want